# Unity: Having trouble in taking screenshot for the content inside scrollView

Tags: unity-game-engine, screenshot

I am new in Unity. I'm trying to make a code that will take a screenshot of a object inside scrollview. My problem is that the whole object/image inside the scrollView is not visible in device.YOu have to pan the scrollView to see the hidden part.What I wanna do is to take the screenshot of the whole object/image inside the scrollview. Please help

My code below is

```
    private IEnumerator TakeScreenshot()
    {
    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();

    var width = Screen.width;
    var height = Screen.height;
    var tex = new Texture2D(width, height, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
    // Read screen contents into the texture
    tex.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, width, height), 0, 0);
    tex.Apply();
    byte[] screenshot = tex.EncodeToPNG();
}
```

Code above only takes the screenshot that is visible to the device screen. I want to take the screenshot the whole object/image. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Just point a camera with render texture setup towards your object and use the encode function.

Use of render texture and `encodeToPng` is recommended.

Your code simply creates a texture and reads the first pixel in it and doesn't do anything with it.